# Get material by name in SceneKit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I have imported a collada .dae file into scenekit.
I can see in the scene editor/inspector that there is a list of Entities and Materials with named materials. But I have no clue how to ask for these programatically.

I can ask for the material by name from a geometry object if I know one node and geometry that uses it, like so:

```
myscene.rootNode.childNodes[68].geometry?.materialWithName("carpaint")
```

But these are reusable materials used on many sub geometries, so there should be a global index somewhere(?)

I would have expected something like

```
myscene.materialWithName("carpaint")
```

Comment: A method I commonly use is to add an inconspicuous object somewhere in the scene that uses all materials, and reference material from there. At least it's faster than iterating through all the nodes in the scene looking for a material.

Answer (score 3):

What I ended up with doing was to create an extension to SCNNode and SCNScene to give me an index to all the materials:

```
import SceneKit

extension SCNScene {
    func buildMaterialIndex() -> Dictionary<String, SCNMaterial> {
        return self.rootNode.buildMaterialIndex()
    }
}

extension SCNNode {
    func isPartOf(node: SCNNode) -> Bool {
        return (node === self) || (parentNode?.isPartOf(node) ?? false)
    }

    private class _DictBox {
        var dict = Dictionary<String, SCNMaterial>()
    }
    private func _populateMaterialIndex(dictbox: _DictBox, node: SCNNode) {
        if let g = node.geometry {
            for m in g.materials {
                if let n = m.name {
                    dictbox.dict[n] = m
                }
            }
        }
        for n in node.childNodes {
            _populateMaterialIndex(dictbox, node: n)
        }
    }
    func buildMaterialIndex() -> Dictionary<String, SCNMaterial> {
        let dictbox = _DictBox()
        _populateMaterialIndex(dictbox, node: self)
        return dictbox.dict
    }
}
```